# Iterating through dataframes?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

```
dflist = [DP, SMP, SMD, MP, MD, MSM, SAP, SAD,SAMA, SAM, AP,AD, ASM, AM,ASA]

for i, df in enumerate(dflist):
    # open an existing document
    doc = docx.Document()

    # add a table to the end and create a reference variable
    # extra row is so we can add the header row
    t = doc.add_table(dflist[i].shape[0]+1, dflist[i].shape[1])

    # add the header rows.
    for j in range(dflist[i].shape[-1]):
        t.cell(0,j).text = dflist[i].columns[j]

    # add the rest of the data frame
    for i in range(dflist[i].shape[0]):
        for j in range(dflist[i].shape[-1]):
            t.cell(i+1,j).text = str(dflist[i].values[i,j])

    # save the doc
    doc.save(fr'./test1[i].docx')
```

I am trying to iterate through the list of dataframes so that I create a word document for each of them.

However, I am getting the following error;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-d61049a379a0> in <module>
     14     for i in range(dflist[i].shape[0]):
     15         for j in range(dflist[i].shape[-1]):
---> 16             t.cell(i+1,j).text = str(dflist[i].values[i,j])
     17 
     18     # save the doc

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

How would you write the above code?

Comment: Looks like one of your `DataFrame` is empty?

Comment: Why do you use `dflist[i]` at all when you have `df` available?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all if you use

```
for i, df in enumerate(dflist):
```

then `df` variable represents dataframe from the list `dfList`. And inside the loop you can use this variable `df` if needed access iterated dataframe (instead of `dfList[i]`).

2. You have two `i` variables, and second one "suppress" the value of initial `i` value. First `i` defined in outer loop, and second in inner.

May be something like this will be helpful:

```
for df in dflist:
    # open an existing document
    doc = docx.Document()

    # add a table to the end and create a reference variable
    # extra row is so we can add the header row
    t = doc.add_table(df.shape[0]+1, df.shape[1])

    # add the header rows.
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
        t.cell(0,j).text = df.columns[j]

    # add the rest of the data frame
    for i in range(df.shape[0]):
        for j in range(df.shape[1]):
            t.cell(i+1,j).text = str(df.values[i,j])

    # save the doc
    doc.save(fr'./test1[i].docx')
```

Comment: Thank you Ihor! What would you do to edit the code?

Comment: It's difficult to write exact working code because i don't know what is `doc` object, but may be updated code helps

Comment: Thank you sir!!